# How to use ansi colors in fzf --header?

Tags: vim, neovim, ansi-colors, fzf, vim-fzf

I have try to change the font color in fzf's header.

Here's an example: https://github.com/linrongbin16/fzfx.vim/blob/fa1723e8185e3c2e3d45b6937383ef283c0d3297/autoload/fzfx/vim.vim#L88

But the ansi color code is not working, it just prints:

```
:: Press [0;31mCTRL-G[0m to fuzzy search
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the escape character before the ANSI sequence.

There are several ways how to represent this character. To type it literally in vim do <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd> in insert mode. In vim that character is displayed as `^[` with special highlighting, so it should eventually look:

[image]

Alternatively, you are better to fix `set_ansi_color()`:

```
function! s:set_ansi_color(content)
    return nr2char(0x1B).s:ansi_colors.red.a:content.s:ansi_colors.clear
endfunction
```

Comment: I finally fixed in: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/discussions/3332#discussioncomment-6180823